# How do i check my nat type using stun? New on this

Tags: port, nat, stun

i want to know my nat type, i was trying with this command "netsh interface Teredo show state" however someone suggested me that i should ie a stun server or client to have a better idea of my nat. But i dont have any idea of this, i just want to have an open nat to play games, so please be patient with me :)

By the way i have enabled DMZ and UPNP on my modem.

```
Server Name             : win1910.ipv6.microsoft.com.
Client Refresh Interval : 20 seconds
Client Port             : unspecified
State                   : qualified
Client Type             : teredo client
Network                 : unmanaged
NAT                     : symmetric (port)
NAT Special Behaviour   : UPNP: Yes, PortPreserving: Yes
```

I googled for stun clients or servers but they dont have any info on how to install them or use them, like this one https://github.com/moien007/STUN so if someone can help me with an app that is easy to install or some instructions on how to install a stun server or client please.

Thank you very much.

Edit runing stuntcode.exe got this

```
Result of CTestDataStream: PASS
Result of CTestReader: PASS
Result of CTestBuilder: PASS
Result of CTestIntegrity: PASS
Result of CTestMessageHandler: PASS
Result of CTestCmdLineParser: PASS
Testing detection for DirectMapping
Testing detection for EndpointIndependent mapping
Testing detection for AddressDependentMapping
Testing detection for AddressAndPortDependentMapping
Testing detection for EndpointIndependentFiltering
Testing detection for AddressDependentFiltering
Testing detection for AddressAndPortDependentFiltering
Result of CTestClientLogic: PASS
Result of CTestRecvFromEx(IPV4): PASS
Result of CTestRecvFromEx(IPV6): PASS
Result of CTestFastHash: PASS
Result of CTestPolling: PASS
Result of CTestAtomicHelpers: PASS
Result of CTestRateLimiter: PASS
```

Comment: `stuntestcode.exe` is the test code. you should just ignore that executable. Instead, type `stunclient.exe --help` and read it.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Needing to know your NAT type is a very specialized type of query - and based on you've been asking and commenting, I'm not sure if you really are meant to know this.

Comment: @selbie i just want to know if i have an open nat so i can play videogames without the restrictions that you get with strict nat.

Comment: @neta333 - most video games are client/server, so it probably doesn't matter. Might be a bigger issue for peer-to-peer games.  But if you type `stunclient.exe stun.stunprotocol.org --mode behavior` , I can give you guidance on what the output means.

Comment: @selbie thank you very much. here is the output Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.0.107:57420
Mapped address: 200.194.54.136:77540
Behavior test: success
Nat behavior: Endpoint Independent Mapping

Comment: `Endpoint Independent` is what you want to see to indicate a NAT that is well behaved and likely to yield direct connections without the need for a relay server.  It means you likely do not have a symmetric NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a STUN client application for all platforms at https://www.stunprotocol.org  (prebuilt EXE clients for Windows and Mac command line apps are up there too!)

Demonstration:

```
C:\StunServer> stunclient.exe stunserver.stunprotocol.org --mode behavior
Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.1.7:52707
Mapped address: 101.102.33.44:52707
Behavior test: success
Nat behavior: Endpoint Independent Mapping


C:\StunServer> stunclient.exe stunserver.stunprotocol.org --mode filtering
Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.1.7:39843
Mapped address: 101.102.33.44:39843
Filtering test: success
Nat filtering: Address Dependent Filtering
```

Running the two test modes, reveals Endpoint Independent Mapping and Address Dependent Filtering as described in [RFC 5780](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5780) for classifying NATs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my first post with the results because. Sorry for my lack of experience.

Comment: However when i run stuntclient it stays "Usage: stunclient [OPTIONS] server [port]"

Comment: @neto333 - literally do exactly what I typed above. e.g. `stunclient.exe stun.stunprotocol.org --mode behavior`